# Manipulate with DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I have defined a set of differential equations stored in sol and I'd like to plot them while being able to change the parameters. I've tried it like so:

```
    Manipulate[
    sol = DSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == -b x[t], 
    Derivative[1][p][t] == -(1 - r) p[t] + b x[t], x[0] == 100, 
    p[0] == 10}, {x[t], p[t]}, t], 
  Plot[Evaluate[p[t] /. sol[[1, 1]], {t, 0, 10}], {b, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1}]
 ]
```

but I'm receiving the error message:

> "Manipulate argument Plot[Evaluate[p[t]/. \
>   sol[[1,1]],{t,0,10}],{b,0,1},{r,0,1}] does not have the correct form \
>   for a variable specification."

Any idea how I can fix this? I'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors. See below for corrected code:

```
Manipulate[
 sol = DSolve[
        {Derivative[1][x][t] == -b x[t], 
         Derivative[1][p][t] == -(1 - r) p[t] + b x[t], 
         x[0] == 100, p[0] == 10},
        {x[t], p[t]}, t
       ]; 
 Plot[Evaluate[p[t] /. sol[[1, 1]]], {t, 0, 10}],
 {b, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't because I didn't have enough "points". I have now so it's done :)

Comment: @phytab Thank you!