# How to make a Dynamic Plot of a Differential Function?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, functions, manipulate, dynamic

I'm currently trying to make an educational aid that would graph the position of an object as derived from a second order differential equation. What I would like is for the graph to change as I change the various constants of the equation.

What I currently have looks like this:

```
a = Manipulate[
  DSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 5, x'[0] == 0}, 
   x[t], t], {b, 1, 20, .1}, {m, 1, 20, .1}, {k, 1, 20, .1}]

f[t_] = x[t] /. a[[1]];

Dynamic[Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 20}]]
```

The manipulate works fine, it provides sliders and will output a correctly solved x(t) for the differential for whatever constants I change the sliders to. However, the plot doesn't update as the sliders update. Any advice on how to get the plot to correctly update would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120128/7167) Q&A answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Using Manipulate. It is best to keep everything inside Manipulate, and not have separate functions outside.

[image]

code

```
Manipulate[
 tick;
 sol = x[t] /. 
   First@DSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, 
      x'[0] == xd0}, x[t], t];
 Plot[sol, {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, 
  ImagePadding -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y(t)", None}, {"t (sec)", "Solution to ODE"}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  BaseStyle -> 14],

 Grid[{
   {"damping b",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[b, {b = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {1, 20, .1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[b]
    },

   {"mass m",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[m, {m = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {1, 20, .1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[m]
    },

   {"stifness k",
    Manipulator[Dynamic[k, {k = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {1, 20, .1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[k]
    },

   {"x(0)",
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[x0, {x0 = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 20, .1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[x0]
    },

   {"x'(0)",
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[xd0, {xd0 = #; tick = Not[tick]} &], {0, 20, .1}, 
     ImageSize -> Tiny], Dynamic[xd0]
    }
   }, Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Frame -> True],

 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{m, 1}, None},
 {{b, 1}, None},
 {{k, 1}, None},
 {{x0, 5}, None},
 {{xd0, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{func = 
    x[t] /. DSolve[{m*x''[t] + b*x'[t] + k*x[t] == 0, x[0] == 5, 
        x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t][[1, 1]]}, Plot[func, {t, 0, 20}]], {b, 
  1, 20, .1}, {m, 1, 20, .1}, {k, 1, 20, .1}]
```

I use `With` as a quick and easy way to avoid substitution problems with putting `DSolve` in `Plot`.